# Printing the location of an item from a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Say that I have a list the looks something like this:

```
alist = [3 , "bb", "tc", "a", 41, 93, "lo", "fi", 99, 10]
```

Now let's say the user inputs an the name of an integer or string that's located in the list, how would you use the location of that item in the code ?
For example if the user inputs "tc" i'd like the code to return "2".
How would you go about doing that ? I know it's a noobish question but I just can't seem to remember how to do it.

Comment: Use `dir(list)` if you forget methods related to an object. BTW are you doing this multiple times?(If list is huge and items are unique then dict might be better)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists have an [index method](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
>>> alist = [3 , "bb", "tc", "a", 41, 93, "lo", "fi", 99, 10]
>>> alist.index('tc')
2
```

> Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

```
>>> alist.index('nothing')
...
ValueError: 'nothing' is not in list
```

Note that only the first occurrence is returned if the value appears multiple times:

```
>>> alist = [2, 3, 4, 3, 2]
>>> alist.index(3)
1
```

Comment: Great answer, got the point. Thanks ! @Ashwini Chaudhary, thanks for the comment.